# Firefox save document window hides document

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I apologize in advance this problem seems so strange to me that I can't even properly search for it... Quite often I have to save PDFs from the browser using the download option.

[image]

This is all fine but in the next step, when I click save I get prompted the 'save as' window. And this window is locked to the Firefox Window behind it. That means if I try to move it the Browser window behind it moves with it.

Why do I want to move it? Because I would like to see the title and the authors of the document in order to give the file a meaningful title. This is no longer possible for me.

This started happening after I updated to Ubuntu 20.04. I find this behaviour quite irritating and would be very glad for any suggestions on how to resolve this.

Sorry for not providing more information at this point, I'm really a bit at a loss what could be happening here. But happy to follow up.

Comment: This is what you need https://askubuntu.com/questions/109321/how-to-detach-modal-dialogs-from-main-window-popup-dialogs-attached-to-window-t .

Comment: Yes!! Thank you! Just like the poster in the link you provided I did not even have the right vocabulary to search for it - sorry for duplicating it :)

Comment: Glad to help. Added as proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was already [answered on AskUbuntu.SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/109321/how-to-detach-modal-dialogs-from-main-window-popup-dialogs-attached-to-window-t). It is a "Attached Modal Dialogs" setting that can be changed with GNOME Tweak Tool.